# Does this kind of function have special name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, terminology, binary-operations

Assume i have a function (or binary operation) $f(a,b)$ such that $f(a,b_1) \ne f(a,b_2)$ if $b_1 \ne b_2$ and $f(a_1,b) \ne f(a_2, b)$ if $a_1 \ne a_2$. For example addition satisfies this property ($a + b_1 \ne a + b_2$), but multiplication does not ($a_1 \cdot 0 = a_2 \cdot 0$). Notice that if $a_1 \ne a_2$ and $b_1 \ne b_2$ at the same time, than it is possible but not necessary that $f(a_1,b_1) = f(a_2,b_2)$.
Does this kind of function (or function property) have special name?

Comment: Bi-injective maybe ? (Not to be confused with bijective). Or *partially* injective (as opposed to just injective when seen as a function of a pair).

Comment: "Injective in each argument"?

Comment: Bi-injective is short, but i think the reader will confuse it with bijection. Injective in each  argument clearly states what i mean, but too long. Well may be di-injective will sound fine?

Comment: I would call it separately injective (as in separately continuous).

Comment: Partially injective is cool, but sounds like there is a subset of pairs $\{(a,b)\} \in A \times B $ where function is injective. Separately injective sounds fine, but it sounds like the whole function is not injective (but it can), only by arguments.

Comment: I think i will choose Injective in each argument.