# Function that is injective in each argument separately

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

What do you call a function $f(x,y)$ such that for all $a,b$,
$$y\mapsto f(a,y)\quad \text{ is injective, and}$$
$$x\mapsto f(x,b)\quad \text{ is injective.}$$
For example, linear functions: $f(x,y)=2x-3y+5$ over $\mathbb R$, or the Boolean XOR function.

Comment: Asked before (but not answered): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731057/does-this-kind-of-function-have-special-name ... two suggestions there: "bi-injective" and "injective in each argument"

Answer (score 2):

In case there is no canonical term for such a function, let's gather a list of suggestions:

- **Component-wise injective**
- **Projectively injective** (because you're saying the induced maps you get from the *projections* of the domain $X \times Y$ onto either component are injective)
- **Multi-injective** or in the case of two arguments **biinjective**, by analogy with multilinear and bilinear